# Babel CLI is extremely slow

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

So I follow the installation [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/), but babel takes very long time to compile, even small files:

**app.js**

```js
let app = 1;
```

**.babelrc**

```
{ "presets": ["es2015"] }
```

**package.json**

```js
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel app.js -o dist/app.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13"
}
```

Then `npm run build` will take ~30s to compile.

I'm using `npm@3.3.12`

Comment: Can't reproduce. What happens when you run the command directly without NPM? `node_modules/.bin/babel app.js -o dist/app.js`

Comment: If you're on npm 3 you should be good. Maybe clear your node_modules and reinstall to be sure? Or look in node_modules and make sure your dependencies are all flattened properly.

Comment: Yes that came from my install, ``rm -rf node_modules``, ``npm cache clean``and ``npm install``did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You might be compiling `node_modules` and `bower_components` too.

You can try adding the `ignore` property in your projects `.babelrc` like so:

```
{
  ...
  "ignore": /(node_modules|bower_components)/
  ...
}
```

Hope this solves your issue

Answer (score 1):

**Update September 2019**

Found upgrading to Babel 7 solved this. Perhaps try:

```
$ npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/node @babel/preset-env
```

Your package.json should contain something like:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.6.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.0"
  }
```

My `.babelrc` file is as follows:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Now, when I run:

```
npx babel-node src/index.js
```

the performance is almost instantaneous (it was taking 20+ seconds with babel 6).

See the [babel 7.5 docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-node) for more details on this.

Also, for reference on the upgrade, see [this stackoverflow question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092739/upgrade-to-babel-7-cannot-read-property-bindings-of-null/52092788).