# Upgrade to Babel 7: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I just upgraded to [Babel 7](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/index.html) (from 6) by running these commands:

```
npm remove babel-cli
npm install --save-dev @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

Here is my `.babelrc` file:

```
{ "presets": ["env"] }
```

Then I ran:

```
babel js/src --out-dir js/dist
```

And it results in:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null
    at Scope.moveBindingTo (/xyz/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/scope/index.js:867:13)
    at BlockScoping.updateScopeInfo (/xyz/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:364:17)
    at BlockScoping.run (/xyz/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:330:12)
    at PluginPass.BlockStatementSwitchStatementProgram (/xyz/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:70:24)
    at newFn (/xyz/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:193:21)
    at NodePath._call (/xyz/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:53:20)
    at NodePath.call (/xyz/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/xyz/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:88:12)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/xyz/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:118:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/xyz/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:90:19)
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 378, accepted):

In your `.babelrc` file, change

```
{ "presets": ["env"] }
```

to

```
{ "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"] }
```

(and install that package if you haven't already).

In your `.babelrc` you are still referencing the package `babel-preset-env` (which is for 6.x), you want to reference `@babel/preset-env` instead (which is for 7.x).

> https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6186#issuecomment-366556833

**Note:** you should also make this change in `webpack.config.js` if it is there as well.

Here is the sample webpack config section where you should change the preset:

```
use: {
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    // Here you should change 'env' to '@babel/preset-env'
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
  },
},
```

Comment: Note you should also make this change in `webpack.config.js` if it is there as well.

Comment: also important to mention to install @babel/preset explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61889105/6221709

Comment: @mangrove108 *(and install that package if you haven't already)*. This post is not about "how do I install an npm package".

Comment: @connexo well it was helpful to me. Thx mangrove108