# Possible spread error on IE 11 (Webpack, VueJS)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

I'm getting this error on IE 11:

[image]
[image]

Here are my webpack and babel configuations:

webpack configuration

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const StylishWebpackPlugin = require('webpack-stylish');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

const withLogRocket = process.argv.includes('--with-logrocket');
if (withLogRocket) {
  /* eslint-disable no-console */
  console.info('-> Building with LogRocket enabled.');
  /* eslint-enable */
}

// Base webpack configuration for all environments.
module.exports = {
  context: path.dirname(__dirname),
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js',
  },
  target: 'web',

  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    hashDigestLength: 8,
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    },
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  stats: 'errors-only',

  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      tslint: true,
      reportFiles: ['src/**/*.ts'],
    }),
    new StylishWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      USE_LOGROCKET: withLogRocket,
    }),
  ],
};
```

babelrc file

```
{
    "presets": ["env"],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-destructuring",
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

I'm not really sure if this is due to the `...sources` spread or among others. I'm pretty sure I have the `babel-transform-object-rest-spread` package but I still don't get why I have this error, I also used `babel-preset-env`. As you can see on the configuration I am running a pure JS (VueJS, typescript) app. I've read numerous posts about using polyfill and among others but it didn't help me make our app run on IE11.

Comment: Note that the line in question there is *argument* spread, which is different from object spread (not sure if that matters)

Comment: Oh okay, so how do I fix this on IE11? :D

Comment: You're using  `env` preset but never defining what enviroment Babel is supposed to generate code for (so I assume IE 11 is not supported in that case) .

Answer (score 2):

You're using  `env` preset but never defining what environment Babel is supposed to generate code for (so I assume IE 11 is not supported in that case).

> Without any configuration options, babel-preset-env behaves exactly the same as babel-preset-latest (or babel-preset-es2015, babel-preset-es2016, and babel-preset-es2017 together).

So just add the options object having the `targets` property set to something the like of

```
"browsers": [ "last 1 version", "ie >= 11" ]
```

like this:

```
{
    "presets": ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": [ "last 1 version", "ie >= 11" ]
      }
    }],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-destructuring",
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

I also highly recommend you switch to Babel 7 asap.

Comment: Didn't work as well. I still have the same error as above.

Comment: @TheBassman Which is because `babel-loader` by default does **not** use `.babelrc` file. That was changed/fixed only in `babel-loader>=8.0.0` (which is for **Babel 7** (as I recommended to switch to asap)). For a fix with Babel 6.x: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/552#issuecomment-355341074

Comment: Sorry took time to respond, I upgraded my `babel-core` to *7.1.6* and still it didn't work..

Comment: You need to update all babel-related packages. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration Also remember to upgrade `babel-loader` to version 8.x. You might find other babel-related packages in your package.json. Also you need to update the babel-plugins (I'd suggest you first try without any).

Comment: Also you need to adjust your `.babelrc` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092739/upgrade-to-babel-7-cannot-read-property-bindings-of-null/52092788#52092788