# Babel requiring module that isn't used?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm new to React, webpack, Babel.... all of it. Trying to setup a vanilla project where I want to utilize [Salesforce Lightning Design System for React](https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/getting-started/). `npm run start` shows the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] /Users/brandor/test/react_tut/src/index.js: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-env'
Require stack:
- /Users/brandor/test/react_tut/node_modules/@salesforce/babel-preset-design-system-react/index.js
```

I'm not sure why it's stating that 'babel-preset-env' is required. Shouldn't that have been installed when I installed the slds modules with the following?

`$ npm install @salesforce-ux/design-system @salesforce/design-system-react`

If I do install the module (along with one other it complains about) then I get something that seems to be related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092739/upgrade-to-babel-7-cannot-read-property-bindings-of-null), but I'm using what looks like the correct presets in my `babel.config.js` file.

The other error is:

`TypeError: /Users/brandor/test/react_tut/src/components/App.js: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null` which

Not sure if this is an issue with webpack config, babel, or incorrect version of something.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react_tut",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Boilerplate stuff",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@salesforce-ux/design-system": "^2.11.6",
    "@salesforce/design-system-react": "^0.10.18",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions": "^6.22.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    resolve: {
        modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                include: [
                path.join(__dirname, 'src/js'),
                path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/@salesforce/design-system-react'),
                ],
                exclude: [
                path.join(
                    __dirname,
                    'node_modules/@salesforce/design-system-react/node_modules',
                ),
                ],
                use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    },
                },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(svg|gif|jpe?g|png)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=30&name=assets/fonts/webfonts/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'),
        }),
    ],
};
```

babel.config.js

```
'use strict';

const presets = ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-flow', '@salesforce/babel-preset-design-system-react'];

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ...presets,
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: false,
        corejs: '3',
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
      },
    ],
  ],
  env: {
    test: {
      presets: [
        ...presets,
        [
          '@babel/preset-env',
          {
            targets: { node: 'current' },
            corejs: '3',
            useBuiltIns: 'usage',
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: You're using it as a preset in your babel config.

Comment: Is `@babel/preset-env` really the same as `babel-preset-env`? If you instal both modules they show as separate in a `package.json` file...